# Excel conditional formatting formula if THIS current cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to do something that seems simple in concept at first, yet Googling reveals no pages that explain how to do it, NOR are there and emergent pages that say something with the gist of "*don't bother because it can't be done*". What I'm trying to do is highlight a column of cells in Excel and create a rule that says this (*pseudocode*):

```
If THIS cell is blank
   Change the text color to white and fill color to Red
   Display the text "[INFO NEEDED]" //(without quotes)
```

If the cell is not blank, then the rule will not be triggered.

Unfortunately, when I web search for `excel conditional formatting formula "this cell" blank` I keep wrong answers of two varieties:

1. "How to format cells based on other cells" AND
2. "How to format blank cells" (*but not using a formula approach*)

To be extra clear: I'm **not* looking for how to do it based on values in other cells, nor with the "Format only cells that contain" method.

I realize that it may turn out to be just not possible, but I wanted to run it by the readers on Stack Overflow to see if this can be done, but isn't often, and perhaps gain insight into why.

Comment: By "this cell" do you mean the cell that is currently selected with a mouse click?

Comment: It is not possible to make text appear using conditional formatting. You could use a macro though

Comment: This cannot be done with a CFR because even with forced cell formatting, you cannot have `[INFO NEEDED]` magically appear in a truly blank cell.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to make this pseudocode work using just conditional formatting. 
You can accomplish the first part of the requirement, i.e., check in the condition formula whether the cell is empty (ISBLANK(address)). You cannot, however, change the value of the cell because: 1) Conditional formatting is dealing just with the formatting; 2) The cell will no longer be blank after you have inserted the text; 3) Excell formulas do not allow you to use circular references, i.e., the results that depend on the value in the same formula. What you can do is to use VBA to do this (and to change the cell color inside the function instead of referring to conditional formatting). Please find the suggested code below. A1 must be replaced with an address of a cell that you need to check, and the file must be saved as .xlsm to enable the macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If (IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = True) Then
      Range("A1").Value = "[INFO NEEDED]"
      Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbRed
      Range("A1").Font.Color = vbWhite
    Else
      Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbWhite
      Range("A1").Font.Color = vbBlack
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Or you could insert the text using this method and have conditional formatting for "[INFO NEEDED]"

Comment: Yes, it would not be the most efficient and elegant solution since conditional formatting tends to slow down the execution, and there is a macro already written to change the cell value. But it is definitely doable.

Comment: Ha, I return to this and realise how pointless my comment was now... It's a worksheet_Change so it'll return with the else statement, I orignally was thinking it would be locked in red/white... it's been a long day full of many bugs :D

Comment: @OlesyaRazuvayevskaya Thanks for your reply! I think this is what I was looking for --1) What I want to do is not possible as CF, 2) the reason it isn't possible, and 3) A solution for making it work. I will test it out and if it works I will mark as the correct answer.

Comment: @OlesyaRazuvayevskaya I can't get it to work. Followed this tutorial https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/, but can't save the macro you gave me. Yes, already using xlsm. Thoughts? Here is a link to what I'm attempting (select a column range) I used 'G5' as my start cell number. https://imgur.com/10QeGty

Comment: Regarding the problem with saving the macro, it is hard to tell looking just at your Spreadsheet. If you are inserting the code using the VBA editor and are saving the file using the .xlsm format, it should be saved. Does the code disappear when you re-open the file and go to VBA editor - Sheet1? Do you have macros enables for your workbook? Which version of Excel/Operating system are you using? Another point I noticed on your screenshot is that you seem to be using a whole column rather than just a cell. The code above works for 1 cell, and it needs to be modified to work for the range.

Comment: UPD: I just replicated it on my excel, and it does work fine.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 Worksheet change events can't be called from a module... put it in the worksheet / workbook's code, you might need to use the dropdown in the top right to target the event you want if that still doesn't work...

Comment: @RichardTompsett Thanks for yours and OlesyaRazuvayevskaya's replies. I will implement your advice and report back.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a stab at this:

Rather than providing you with this *specific solution*, I am rather going to try to address the *root of your problem*. It seems that you want to prevent users from inputting blank cells.

Rather than displaying an error message and changing the formatting if a cell is blank, why not just use data validation to simply not even allow blank cells?

You can set up data validation to not allow blank cells, and display an error message if a user tries to input a blank cell. See below.

[image]

[image]

Now if I try to delete the contents of this cell, the following message box appears:

[image]

Again, I realize this doesn't answer your question exactly, but it may provide an alternate solution.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question seemed to me like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: +1 for trying. While I appreciate the solution you offered (I always appreciate screenshots!), it doesn't address the problem I clearly described. I can see why you might have deduced that my question was leaving out information, which prompted your response, however, rest assured that I stated exactly what I was trying to do. If anyone else thinks this is the answer to MY query, it is not, and therefore I cannot mark it as such.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 Understood and that is fine. Thought I would give it a try. Thanks for the +1.